# can pbuilder style hooks be used on launchpad builds

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad, locale

I'm working on putting a project into PPA. The project is large and has lots of tests. A couple of tests require that some locales are installed. To get around this I've made a pbuilder hook that `locale-gen`s the required locales. This works like a charm. The tests pass. If I don't do this pbuilder fails because the tests fail.

Since I don't use the `override_dh_auto_test` target in `debian/rules` to skip the tests I presume that the launchpad build will fail because the tests will fail without the locales.

Is there a way to install the locales on launchpad builds similar to hooks in pbuilder or should I just override the test target before `dput`ting the packages to launchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use pbuilder-style hooks, no.  However, generating locales doesn't require root in principle; it's just the default `locale-gen` arrangements that write to the system locale directories and therefore require root.  You could instead use `localedef` to generate the locales somewhere under your build directory and point your test process at that using `LOCPATH`.

Comment: indeed i just saw that here: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.html#bpp-locale

ill give it a try!

Comment: using `localedef` to generate the locales under the build directory and having the tests point at them using `LOCPATH` worked like a charm thanks again!